# Fetch places from POSTGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have downloaded data from `geonames` and then followed the below link to dump it into POSTGIS.

https://github.com/colemanm/gazetteer/blob/master/docs/geonames_postgis_import.md

I'm not sure how to get places between two routes at the moment. The table has separate columns for `latitude` and `longitude`.

I need to get places between the route, is there anyway of doing it?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Get places between two points :

```
SELECT * FROM geoname WHERE 
ST_DWithin('POINT(44.8781 -116.6298)', 
ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(43.7392 -114.9903)'), 16093.4);
```

I'm getting 0 results, even though I'm sure there are places near these points.

Also I have tried,

```
SELECT * FROM geoname WHERE 
ST_Distance_Sphere('POINT(44.8781 -116.6298)',     
ST_MakePoint(43.7392,-114.9903)) <= 16093.4;
```

Is it something to be done using `pgRouting`. May be something like get a route using `pgRouting` and then get the places along the `path`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you not see the error message "ERROR:  Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type"?

Swap the axis order from *lat lon* (or *Y X*) to the correct axis order *lon lat* (or *X Y*). If you mistakenly created geometry/geography objects with the former axis order, you can update a swapped version with [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html)